# How can I run a cmd script while my computer is off?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cmd

I currently have a cmd script set up on my computer in conjunction with a scheduled task that's supposed to run every 15 minutes. The script runs a python program that is also on my computer and then uploads the file that's created to my Github repository. However, this scheduled task doesn't run when my computer is completely shut down and I don't want to have my computer on 24/7.

Is there a way to run a cmd script with my computer off? I've heard of potential solutions with an Amazon Web Services account or a DigitalOcean droplet, but I'm novice (at best) with my understanding of how that works. Any suggestions or links to resources would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate of "off". Does that mean shut down, on sleep, ...?

Comment: @quicVO completely shut down. Just edited the post!

Comment: What do you mean? You can't run any program on a computer that is shut down? Do you want to start first automatically?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler will start the computer from hibernation to run a scheduled task configured to do so.

Comment: @user14797724 while that's true, if Sam needs to run this task every 15 minutes, really not seeing the point of waking up the PC 4 times an hour to perform the task. Depending on how long it takes to wake, perform the task, and sleep again, it may as well be on 24/7 and that's what they're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to run anything on your computer with it powered off.

You could set up a low-cost Linux VPS with any cloud compute provider (AWS, DigitalOcean, Microsoft Azure, Google Cloud Platform, Vultr, etc.), migrate your python program to it, and schedule that program to run every 15 minutes on there.

[DigitalOcean: How to set up an Ubuntu 20.04 server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ubuntu-20-04-server-on-a-digitalocean-droplet)

You would need to keep that VPS turned on, and in place of Task Scheduler, you could schedule your Python program to run (with any arguments) as a **cron** job.

[DigitalOcean: How to use Cron to automate tasks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804)

Comment: Q: "how to run a program when the computer is off" A: "run it on another computer that isn't off". Getting that accepted and upvoted three times just made my day! (let's make that four upvotes)

Comment: An even cheaper (as in free) option would be an AWS lambda function triggered by a cron expression in cloudwatch.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html